# Error creating files when publishing IOS AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, icons, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so I have this issue now to when I try to publish my Game using Adobe AIR IOS 22.0 Flash CS6 on my iPhone I get this Error"Usage error incorrect arguments...Have conflicting package paths[image: Error Pic] paths

Everything was working fine before I am not sure what is the issue. While googling the error I found some forums of people saying they had the same issue and had to just delete the bin folder? I don't know what they mean by that though. I looked everywhere for a bin folder.

I add my app Icons in my XML like so
 
`<icon>
         <image29x29>iconFolder/ios/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-App-29x29@1x.png</image29x29>
  </icon>`

then in Flash CS6 I add the actual Pngs in the "Included Files" section where my SWF and everything else is.

Please any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe I am adding the answer to this now, years after the question got posted, but just in case it might be helpful to someone in the future. This happened to me a few times in the past, and somehow it got figured out. This time, it took a good while so for documenting the solution, just so that I can find it back on the stack, here it goes. By the way, I am on Adobe Animate CC18, and publishing to Air Desktop. First, I moved my files to a cleaner folder, and then all of a sudden the image icons for app would make the build fail. So, I deleted them, created them in another different folder, and then went to the publishing page on Actionscript 3 for Air Desktop from the file menu, and browsed for the images. This time, Animate asked me if I wanted to copy them in a location relative to the root, which I said yes to. Then, Viola! It worked like a charm. so in summary: Say your app is called "ChatNow and the icons are in the ChatNow/icons/16,32,48,128 folder. Do this

1. Delete the icons from this folder.
2. Create them in a different folder outside of the directory of where ChatNow exists.
3. Go to File/Air 32 [or your version of Air] for Desktop Settings
4. Go the Deployment tab and select the 'Icons' tab.
5. Now browse for the new locations for the icons. You should be prompted by Animate to copy these icons to the folder. Agree, and then try your build.

This worked for me, under the circumstances described. Hope it helps,